# logging urls in IIS

Tags: iis, sql-injection

A little over a year ago we started getting hit with sql injection attacks.  We have hundreds of sites so we ended up spending weeks patching any holes we could find.  Then a few weeks ago we started getting hit again.  We've gone through everything we can think of and we can't find anywhere where the person is getting in.  Does anyone know if there's a way to write a script for IIS that will allow me to record every url or posted data that IIS encounters?  And because we've got so many sites I'm looking to set up something that doesn't have to be set up for each individual site but that I can set up at the root of the IIS tree.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a script for URL data it can logged in the regular IIS logs.

See [this article](http://www.ehow.com/how_4533018_microsoft-internet-information-services-iis.html) about setting up the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The first place too look is the Log files (Assuming you are using IIS 6.0, see [here](http://www.smartertools.com/Portal/KB/a154/how-to-where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx) for a tutorial how to find them)

The IIS log does not store posted Data though. Look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/90943/iis-log-request-body-post-data) for a discussion regarding logging post data.

Comment: Yes that's a start but again we have to go through each site's log files.  It'd be ideal if we could set up something to log all requests so that we only have 1 table of data to search through.

Comment: You would use logparser to interrogate the files see http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1712 for some suggested queries.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, IIS logs all requests to a web site, unless you have unchecked "Enable Logging". You might want to look in to [UrlScan 3.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/473/using-urlscan), which also handles possible [SQL injection scenarios](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/476/common-urlscan-scenarios/), see the section entitled "Rule to Block SQL injection Signatures"

Comment: They also have a data mining section http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/513/data-mining-urlscan-3x-logs-using-logparser-22/